# Solve this PHP database error for me

Tags: php, database

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iwant2`.`product_tb`, CONSTRAINT `fk_clientID` FOREIGN KEY (`clientID`) REFERENCES `client_tb` (`clientID`))
```

Why am I getting this error?

I have the following tables:

- `client_tb`
- `product_tb`
- `category_tb`

I have the `productID`, `clientID` and `categoryID` in `product_tb`. The `clientID` and `categoryID` are in foreign relationship with `product_tb` table.

Comment: what is the query that's causign this error?

Comment: What database are we talking about here?

Comment: Can you give us the exact error and the code that coincides with it?  We're not magicians or mind-readers.

Comment: It isn't complaining about the table structure (which is obvious since you've already created them). It's complaining about your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have built foreign key constraints, but apparently you don't understand their purpose.  A foreign key enforces a business rule, which is the relationship between the referencing and referenced table: the parent table must have a row with a key which matches the referencing key in the child table.

In your scenario a row in the Product_TB needs a Client_ID which matches a row in the Client_TB table.  The error message is telling you that this is not the case.  So, before you can insert that Product you must insert a row for the client.